# 90 days out of 180 in The Netherlands

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens, 90-180-visa-rules

I'm going to The Netherlands (as usual) and was wondering if the times overlapped. For example, I went for about a month in December and am planning to go again this May.

Assuming my 180 days began when I went in December, I will be okay to go again in June?

If I'm already there, will my 180 days reset or will they count my second vacation as going over the amount of days I'm able to stay there?

Comment: What citizenship do you have? For all but a few countries, there is no such thing as the 180 days "resetting" at some threshold anymore; the rule is now "no more than 90 days in *any* 180-day period."

Comment: I have American citizenship.

Comment: In that case, the rules mentioned by @cpast applies so it's neither one nor the other, the 180 days do not reset but you will be able to stay 90 days. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45296/returning-to-schengen-area-visa-questions for a full explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, for every possible 180-day window, you can spend 90 of those days in the Schengen area, regardless of your start and end dates of the journeys. In that sense, maybe it's easier for you to think about it the other way around, like in every 180-day period there should be 90 days that you are **not** in the Schengen area. By leaving a 5-month gap from January till May, you make sure that any 180-day period from (roughly speaking) October to August will contain at least 90 days that you are outside the region, hence is completely legal.